# Click date event can see all the events on that particular date using Angular

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

In the FullCalendar selectDate event, can I get the events that already exist on the selected date? I want to know how many events for that particular date so that, I can do some logics here.

Comment: Fullcalendar doesn't have a "selectDate" event - see the documentation: https://fullcalendar.io/docs#toc . Please make clear which callback/option you are actually referring to specifically. e.g. did you mean "select"? Or perhaps "dateClick"? Or what?

Comment: But in general, to get the number of events on a particular date, you need to ask fullCalendar to give you all the events currently in its list (via https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-getEvents) and you'll need to filter them yourself using JS.

Answer (score 2):

I take it you mean `select` - https://fullcalendar.io/docs/select-callback

In the `select` function, you could use the following to get the list of events already within the selection.

```
select: function( selectionInfo ) {
    var eventsInSelection = calendar.getEvents().filter(x => x.start >= selectionInfo.start && x.end <= selectionInfo.end);

    var numberOfEvents = eventsInSelection.length;

    for(i=0;i<eventsInSelection.length;i++) {
        // do something per event here
    }
}
```

where `calendar` is the reference to your FullCalendar instance.